# Finding first element occurrence with Python

Tags: python, arrays, count, indexing, integer

I have an array of integers:

```
samples = [123,125,125,120,0,132,133,123,123,...,125,0,133,133,120]
```

I had seen methods to find an element in the array. But those examples are looking for one element with no duplicate in the array. In my case, I would like to find the index of '0' but in my array, I have two '0's in it.

If I only have one '0' in the array, this method will work:

```
if sample.count(0)==1:
    b = sample.index(0)
```

and b would contain the position of '0' in the array. If I try it with the array containing two '0's, this wouldn't work any more because of the duplicate. I only want to find the index of the first '0'. How do I solve this?

Comment: `sample.index(0)` will give you the index of the first `0` in `sample`, no matter how many `0`s you have in sample (as long as you have at least one)

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> list.index(x) Return the index in the list of the first item whose
>   value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

So `index` does what you want (it returns the **first** element that you are looking for).